# Filter out results from REST API

Tags: plugins, hooks, rest-api

I want to build a plugin to remove all posts by specific users from rest json output.
How can I add a **filter** or **hook** to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using WP 4.7+ you can filter the query using the [`rest_{$this->post_type}_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) hook `wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php:L267`

This is a working example that filters current query by given terms

```
    $types = [
        'post',
        'page',
    ];

    foreach ( $types as $type ) {
        add_filter( 'rest_' . $type . '_query', 'filter_rest_query_by_zone', 10, 2 );
    }

    function filter_rest_query_by_zone( $args, $request ) {
            $zones = [ 'term1', 'term2', 'term3' ];

            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'zones',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $zones
                )
            );

            return $args;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting to feel like a parrot, but here it goes again :(... If you need results which are different than those returned by the API by default, just create your own end point. The more core will move into utilizing those APIs for admin, the more risky it will get to modify them in any way.

Comment: But I need this because of security, I want to block all users from accessing some spcial posts.

Comment: gutenberg is going to rely on this specific API to work for editing posts. If posts will be removed how will you edit them? You should try @Alex's solution and if it works without gutenberg try with gutenberg to edit post types which you remove from the response.

Answer (score 0):

**Filtering posts based on multiple custom taxonomy terms based on logical "AND", "OR" condition in wordpress rest api.**

Here is what you need to do in the newer versions of Wordpress (v5 and above)

Lets say you have two custom taxonomies: sector and offerings.

Getting all posts that are tagged with taxonomy ID 51 "OR" 52 beloning to the taxonmy term "sector" "OR" Getting all posts that are tagged with taxonomy ID 57 "AND" 58 beloning to the taxonomy term "offering"

```
https://mywordpressbackend.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?sector=51+52&offering=57,58&tax_relation=OR
```

Getting all posts that are tagged with taxonomy ID 51 "OR" 52 beloning to the taxonmy term "sector" "AND" Getting all posts that are tagged with taxonomy ID 57 "AND" 58 beloning to the taxonomy term "offering"

```
https://mywordpressbackend.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?sector=51+52&offering=57,58&tax_relation=AN
```